# Inject value into a static field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is my class:

```
 public class DeduplicationErrorMetric extends AbstractErrorMetric {
    
        public static final String DEDUPLICATIONS_METRIC = "deduplications";
        public static final String KAFKA_MESSAGES_METRIC = "kafka.messages";
    
        private static String DEDUPLICATION_TOPIC_NAME;
    
        private static final List<Tag> DEDUPLICATION_ERROR_TAGS = List.of(Tag.of("type", "failed"));
        private static final List<Tag> KAFKA_ERROR_TAGS = List.of(Tag.of("topic", DEDUPLICATION_TOPIC_NAME),
                Tag.of("action", "send"), Tag.of("result", "failure"));
    
        public DeduplicationErrorMetric() {
            super(Map.of(
                    DEDUPLICATIONS_METRIC, DEDUPLICATION_ERROR_TAGS,
                    KAFKA_MESSAGES_METRIC, KAFKA_ERROR_TAGS
            ));
        }
    
        @Override
        public void incrementMetric(String key) {
            errorCounters.get(key).increment();
        }
    }
```

I have `@Value("${kafka.topic.deduplication}")` in my application.yml, and I need to insert the value into `DEDUPLICATION_TOPIC_NAME` before the bean will be created. How can I do it?

Comment: Don't. Make it an instance field. (You have to instantiate this thing anyway to use it.)

Comment: Why do you need to have this value accessable "before" the bean is instantiated? You should inject this @Value in the constructor.

Comment: Best option is don’t use static. Otherwise there are already questions that cover this. The solutions are all ugly.

Comment: @NathanHughes I had an answer for OP, as I think his problem is a XY problem. Can we reopen it?

Comment: Sorry, reopened it, I thought it was just a vote

Comment: @NathanHughes I posted my answer, please let me know if that was a good decision, if not I'll delete the answer but I think it gives a proper alternative to what OP's trying to achieve

Comment: @Yassin: you have a gold badge so that lets you reopen dupes. I still think best advice is, “don’t do this”.

Comment: @NathanHughes yes that's what I put in the answer, but there's a way to achieve what OP's trying using `@Singleton`, `@PostConstruct` and `@Value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setter to do this but I'd advocate **against this practice** !

1. This means your field will be `null` before a first instance comes and invokes this injection point
2. Your `static` field is not `final` so can lead to modification, thus lead to hard to debug bugs
3. It will not solve your current problem as the `null` value will be used in this case for `KAFKA_ERROR_TAGS`

```
@Value("${kafka.topic.deduplication}")
private void setDeduplicationTopicName(String deduplicationTopicName) {
    this.DEDUPLICATION_TOPIC_NAME = deducplicationTopicName;
}
```

---

Instead, maybe try to create a `@Singleton` bean and use `@Value` on its fields, then you're sure you have only one instance.

For your list, you can then use `@PostConstruct` to make sure it's instantiated once

Answer (score 1):

What you could do here is to directly use injection from a properties file.

If it is a SpringBoot app, in you application properties set your `kafka.topic.deduplication` property (you can have different values for different environments).

This way, Spring will get the value while constructing the bean.

Your code could look something like this:

```
public class DeduplicationErrorMetric extends AbstractErrorMetric {

    public static final String DEDUPLICATIONS_METRIC = "deduplications";
    public static final String KAFKA_MESSAGES_METRIC = "kafka.messages";

    private static final List<Tag> DEDUPLICATION_ERROR_TAGS = List.of(Tag.of("type", "failed"));
    private static final List<Tag> KAFKA_ERROR_TAGS = List.of(Tag.of("topic", deduplicationTopicName),
            Tag.of("action", "send"), Tag.of("result", "failure"));

    @Value("${kafka.topic.deduplication}")
    private String deduplicationTopicName; 
   
    public DeduplicationErrorMetric() {
        super(Map.of(
                DEDUPLICATIONS_METRIC, DEDUPLICATION_ERROR_TAGS,
                KAFKA_MESSAGES_METRIC, KAFKA_ERROR_TAGS
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public void incrementMetric(String key) {
        errorCounters.get(key).increment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the keyword "static" and then you will be able to change it in the instance.

Static means that the field is locked to the class.

```
public class DeduplicationErrorMetric extends AbstractErrorMetric {
    
    public static final String DEDUPLICATIONS_METRIC = "deduplications";
    public static final String KAFKA_MESSAGES_METRIC = "kafka.messages";
    
    private String DEDUPLICATION_TOPIC_NAME;
    
    private static final List<Tag> DEDUPLICATION_ERROR_TAGS = List.of(Tag.of("type", "failed"));
    private List<Tag> KAFKA_ERROR_TAGS = List.of(Tag.of("topic", DEDUPLICATION_TOPIC_NAME),
            Tag.of("action", "send"), Tag.of("result", "failure"));
    
    public DeduplicationErrorMetric() {
        super(Map.of(
                DEDUPLICATIONS_METRIC, DEDUPLICATION_ERROR_TAGS,
                KAFKA_MESSAGES_METRIC, KAFKA_ERROR_TAGS
        ));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void incrementMetric(String key) {
        errorCounters.get(key).increment();
    }
    
    public void setTopic(String value){
        DEDUPLICATION_TOPIC_NAME = value;   
    }
}

private void example(){
    DeduplicationErrorMetric dem = new DeduplicationErrorMetric();
    
    //Set the instance value directly
    dem.DEDUPLICATION_TOPIC_NAME = "Test";
    
    //Set via a function, potentially with other variables. 
    demo.setTopic("Test");
}
```

I would also recommend making the variable name lowercase now that it is not static, as good coding practice.

Comment: But then the variable cant be used in the static list underneath...